# Создание компонента с использованием именованных слотов

Tags: vue.js

Пытаюсь создать компонент по типу `<table>`, как это было сделано во Vuetify, чтобы можно было переиспользовать данный компонент несколько раз. Проблема в том, что таблиц много и всё что находится в `<tbody>` разное, поэтому использую `v-slot` для решения этой проблемы, но у меня не получается в родительском компоненте получить данные из слота.

Например, как вариант, в компоненте *Table.vue* каким-то образом сделать слот тегом `<tr>`:

**list.vue**

```
<Table :headers="tableHeader" :items="fetchItems">
  <template v-slot:items="props">
    <td>{{ props.item.title }}</td>
  </template>
</Table>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        tableHeader: [{
          name: "title",
          sort: false
        }, {
          name: "description",
          sort: false
        }],
        fetchItems: [{
          title: "book 1"
        }, {
          title: "book 2"
        }]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**table.vue**

```
<template>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="(item, index) in headers" :key="index">{{item.name}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <slot name="items" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index"></slot>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      headers: {},
      items: {}
    }
  }
</script>
```

---

Как можно решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `v-slot` есть собственное сокращение, например, `v-slot:thead` можно записать как `#thead`.

Передача данных в дочерний компонент осуществляется ч/з `v-bind` и связыванием с объектом, содержащим атрибуты.

В дочернем компоненте указываем слот для каждой итерации, передавая объект `row` в качестве входного параметра.

В родительском при использовании `<filterable>`, можно опционально переопределить `<template>` для элементов списка, но сохранив доступ к данным из дочернего компонента, т.е. те самые, что определены при итерации.

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

Vue.component('filterable', {
  template: `
    <table v-if="collection.length" class="table table-sm">
      <thead><slot name="thead"></slot></thead>
      <tbody><slot name="row" v-for="item in collection" :row="item"></slot></tbody>
      <tfoot><slot name="tfoot"></slot></tfoot>
    </table>`,
  props: ['resource'],
  computed: {
    collection() {
      return this.$props.resource
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('books-list', {
  template: `
    <filterable v-bind="filterable">
      <template #thead><tr><th>#</th><th>Заголовок</th><th>Автор</th></tr></template>
      
      <template #row="{row}">
        <tr><td>{{ row.id }}</td><td>{{ row.title }}</td><td>{{ row.author }}</td></tr>
      </template>

      <template #tfoot><tr><td>#</td><td>Заголовок</td><td>Автор</td></tr></template>
    </filterable>`,
  data() {
    return {
      filterable: {
        resource: [
          {id: 28,title:"Инферно",author:"Дэн Браун"},
          {id: 48,title:"Игра престолов",author:"Джордж Мартин"},
          {id: 58,title:"Оно",author:"Стивен Кинг"},
          {id: 73,title:"Бойцовский клуб",author:"Чак Паланик"}
        ],
      }
    }
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {}
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #222;
  background-color: #f5f8fa;
}

.table {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table thead th,
.table tfoot td {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
}

.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <books-list></books-list>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10"></script>
```

> В версии 2.6.0 был представлен новый единый синтаксис (директива `v-slot`) для именованных слотов и слотов с ограниченной областью видимости. Он заменяет атрибуты `slot` и `slot-scope`, которые в настоящий момент объявлены устаревшими, но *не* удалены. *-- [источник](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81)*

**NB** Получать данные (ajax запрос) лучше в дочернем компоненте, а из родительского передавать ссылку или модель `api` запросов.